# Questions about the verb "coin" when coining an idea

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, terminology

I want to say "[Rieger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joerg_Rieger) coined the notion of *deep solidarity*." However, I'm not sure about several aspects of this:

1. Can you *coin* a notion, or only a phrase?
2. Can I say he coined the phrase, even if other people used these words with their typical meanings, but he first defined them in a technical sense different than merely "strong solidarity"? (See [Rieger's definition of the phrase](https://books.google.com/books?id=woNUCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA158) and [others discussing it](https://books.google.com/books?id=X48YDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA112))
3. How might others suggest I word this statement?

Comment: I can find examples for ["coined the idea"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22coined%20the%20idea%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) and ["coined the notion"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22coined%20the%20notion%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) on Google Books.

Comment: @NVZ - Does that mean it's acceptable - or, is it merely evidentiary?

Comment: Rieger first identified the concept of...

Comment: To "coin" means to take a piece of nondescript metal and stamp it with a pattern that makes it a recognizable piece of money.  In other words, create something of clear, discernible value out of raw materials.  Other meanings are metaphors on that concept.

Comment: The usual metaphorical collocation for creating a new idea is 'to conceive an idea' ('concept' is already a dead metaphor)

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: One can certainly *espouse a notion*, and it can be an original one, not just one that you've adopted. That last bit is a bit odd, and probably qualifies this usage as idiomatic. "In Émile[,] Rousseau captured the imagination of Europe with his validation of Nature, which **espoused the notion** of the natural goodness of children and the corrupting effects of certain kinds of education: 'Let us lay it down as an incontestable maxim that the first promptings of nature are always right.' ...", Excerpted from *Child Welfare: England 1872-1989* by Harry Hendrick, 1994.

Answer (score 1):

> [coin (v.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/coin) ...General sense of "**make, fabricate, invent**" (words) is from 1580s; phrase coin a phrase is attested from 1940 (to coin phrases is from 1898)... [from *Etymonline*]

As mentioned in both of the previous answers, the phrase **to coin** originally meant to "make", "fabricate", or "invent" -- and ought to be reasonably applicable as well to *notions* (ideas), since words and phrases themselves represent ideas.

Answer (score 0):

"To coin" did originally mean to invent but it's come more often to mean almost the opposite: "to use a well-known phrase…"

However, "more often" doesn't mean exclusively or even instead. To "first define them in a technical sense…" seems to combine both uses; perhaps to introduce a third.

https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/coin-a-phrase.html

Answer (score 0):

To "coin" means to take a piece of nondescript metal and stamp it with a pattern that makes it a recognizable piece of money. In other words, create something of clear, discernible value out of raw materials. Other meanings are metaphors on that concept.

Answer (score -2):

**1.** No. To coin means to create or stamp a phrase as your own e.g. 'shall I compare thee to a summer's day? Thou art more lovely and more temperate.'-William Shakespeare or Arnold Schwarzenegger's phrase-'I'll be back'.

**2.** As I just said-no. It would have to be their own phrase or their catchphrase.

**3.** Rieger used the notion '*deeply solitary*'.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please consider adding sources to support your answers.

Answer (score -2):

> Can you coin a notion, or only a phrase?

You coin a phrase, not a notion.

> Can I say he coined the phrase,

I wouldn't call that particular phrase novel enough for anyone to say they coined it.

You could say he developed an idea or methodology or whatever which he called *deep solidarity*, or he characterized an idea or methodology or whatever, and he called it *deep solidarity*.  The point is, the idea is what's novel, the label he put on it isn't that novel.

Comment: Use research when possible to back up your assertions. Or even to discover that your assertion is wrong, and avoid posting an incorrect answer.